# Want to link foreign key's element and display item according to id of parent element in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I have a json like

```
     $scope.posts = [
{postId:'1',title: 'Beautiful Restaurant',topic: 'Beautiful Restaurant', upvotes: 5, rating:1, image:'img/restaurant1.jpg',
  comments: [
{commentId:'11',postId:'1',author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 6},
{commentId:'12',postId:'1',author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 2}
   ]}
```

And here is the HTML part

```
<h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
<p>{{post.topic}}</p>
<img ng-src="{{post.image}}"  /><br>
<div><button ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)">Like</button>
  Upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}<div class="star-rating" star-rating rating-     value="post.rating" data-max="5" on-rating-selected="rateFunction(post.rating)">   </div>
 </div>
<span>
 <input type="button" value="Show Comments" ng-click="ShowHide()" />
 </span>
     <div ng-hide = "IsHidden" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments  | orderBy:'-upvotes'" >

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
            ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)">+</span>
          {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
          <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">{{comment.body}}</span>
          <form ng-submit="addComment()">
          <h3>Add a new comment</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body"></input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </form>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Want to show comment of particular post on click.Basically, I want to link comment with particular post. Cant find out how. If anybody can show similar example or edit help me with the code.

Comment: Is the HTML you're showing inside of an `ng-repeat` looping over `$scope.posts`? If so, is your `IsHidden` a `$scope` property?

Comment: Yes, IsHidden is here.    $scope.IsHidden = true;
            $scope.ShowHide = function () {
                //If DIV is hidden it will be visible and vice versa.
                $scope.IsHidden = $scope.IsHidden ? false : true;
            };